# sql server join tables without primary key using common columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, distinct, primary-key

I have 2 tables

```
     Id   Name   Units sold
     1    n1,       100 
     2    n2,       95 
     3    n3,       84 
     4    n3,       84 
     5    n5,       100 



  Name   Units sold  Excess Units  Table1_Id
     n1,       100      51            9
     n2,       95       43            10
     n3,       84       100           11
     n3,       84       33            12
     n5,       100      10            13
```

I don't have a way to join these 2 tables as the `Table1_Id` is actually the `Id` of a temp table that loads both these tables.
That table gets wiped out after each load.

I want to show excess units in the first table.

So far my approach has been

```
select table1.*, table2.Excess_units from Table1 inner join
Table2 on Table1.Name = Table2.Name and Table1.Units_sold = Table2.Units_Sold
```

However I am worried that I may run into a situation where I get
2 Table2 records and I won't know which one corresponds to the Table1

Eg:

While Selecting `n3` records, how can I associate the `first and second n3` records of `Table1` with the `first and second n3` records of `Table2` ?

Comment: It would help to know more about the data.  E.g., why would `n3` have two different values for excess units?  And if that is valid, is it per location, e.g., 33 excess units in warehouse A but 100 excess units in warehouse B?  Either you need more data persisted (or the correct data-- the actual id from the source table) or you'll need requirements around whether something like summing would work -- total the excess units for a product by name, but not know the origin of the individual values.

Comment: In the future we will get more persisted values, right now its about the data already in the tables. 
The column names and values are all made-up to show the potential issue. I want to join based on common columns and hopefully associate `table1` records with their correct counterparts in `table2`

Comment: Why don't you add a column `Table1_Id` to your first table, and you then only need to join your two table using `Table1_Id`? Your current approach is only base on intuition, no logic provided to make sure getting a correct result.

Comment: I have no way of knowing which `Id`s to put in that column. That's why i tried my join query. `Table1` has 100000 rows, table2 has 11000000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()` to generate a sequence no for joining

```
select *
from
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over(partition by name, units_sold order by name)
    from   Table1
) t1
inner join
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over(partition by name, units_sold order by name)
    from   Table2
) t2
on  t1.name = t2.name and t1.units_sold = t2.units_sold and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Having the same columns or expressions in both the `partition by` and `order by` clauses of a window function is almost always an error. Here, we know that *all rows within each partition will have an identical `name` value*. The row numbers that are assigned are non-deterministic because of this.